# How to pass users through stripe checkout

Tags: google-cloud-functions, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm making an online e-commerce application with next js, firebase, and stripe. When a user clicks on the checkout button, it redirects them to the stripe checkout link. After they pay with that, a request is made to my firebase cloud function to add their order into my firestore database. Ideally, I would be able to pass a user into the stripe link, and then into the cloud function so that the user can view their orders on the website. The problem is that I don't know how to pass a user into the stripe checkout. Are there any methods I could use?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and up-voting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase UID of the user or any other information in metadata for stripe checkout sessions.

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
payment_method_types: ['card'],
metadata: {user_id: <firebaseUID>},
});
```

Metadata is useful for storing additional, structured information on an object. As an example, you could store your user's full name and corresponding unique identifier from your system on a Stripe customer object. In metadata use objects with only simple data, nested objects will give error.

For metadata details you can refer [Document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata?lang=node)
[Stripe Document](https://stripe.com/docs/api)
Process payments with Firebase refer [Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments)